# Create Outlook rule via PowerShell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I'm looking to create a PowerShell script that creates an Outlook rule which delays any email sent out by one minute.

I have very limited PowerShell knowledge and cannot find much information on this.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$namespace  = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("mapi")
$rules = $outlook.session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
$rule = $rules.Create("1MinDelay",$olRuleType::OlRuleSend)
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.AddMinutes(1)
$mail.DeferredDeliveryTime = $date
$rules |
Sort-Object -Property ExecutionOrder |
Format-Table -Property Name, ExecutionOrder, Enabled, isLocalRule -AutoSize
```

Comment: Are you an Exchange administrator? There are a number of ways to do this. Also in line 8 of your code, you refer to the variable `$mail ` which doesn't appear to be set elsewhere. Should that say `$rule.DeferredDeliveryDate = $date`? Lastly, you haven't said what is not working about your code.

Comment: Hi John, I haven't got a clue why it doesn't work and what I require for it to work. That code is just something I've thrown together.

Answer (score 0):

`olRuleActionDefer` is not Supported when [creating new rules programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868996.aspx),

As a workaround, try to create a new `olRuleSend` type rule and Apply the `olRuleActionDefer` to it, I have not tested it but i think it's possible

Creating Outlook rules through Powershell is explained and exemplified by The Scripting Guy [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/12/16/hey-scripting-guy-december-16-2009.aspx).